# Why the datatype 'int' is enclosed in brackets in the following code

Tags: java

```
    return ( a * (int)(Math.pow(r, N - 1)) );
```

Pls  help me out ...why the datatype 'int' is enclosed in brackets

Comment: Its Type casting

Comment: This is explicit type conversion notation.

Answer (score 0):

Type casting (Math.pow(r, N - 1)) to int

Refer this : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-conversion-java-examples/

Answer (score 0):

`Math.pow(..)` returns a `double` and typecasting is needed to convert it into an `int`.  It is a static function defined in `Math`. More you can see here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Answer (score -1):

`Math.pow() is returning double value.`
If you did not type cast before return, result will be a double value. 
I think in your function, it return int value.
So here type casting value into to int.